# Custom range button doesn't show icon

Tags: css

I am trying to add a button to my custom slider. Here is [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrzswv0f/).

Here is my CSS:

```css
input[type="range"] {
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EDF1F0), to(#F6F8F7));
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  content: '>';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

input[type="range"]:before {
  content: "Modtag penge";
  color: #8a8a8a;
  position: absolute;
  left: 36%;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 56px;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: "→";
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-1-2/380/Arrow_Right2-512.png');
}
```

```html
<input #unlock type="range" class="slideToUnlock" value="0" max="100" (touchend)="checkUnlock($event)" (mouseout)="checkUnlock($event)">
```

Comment: there is no before for slider-thumb .. remove it and you will get the image: https://jsfiddle.net/3mje7oza/

Comment: @TemaniAfif i dont see that from your fiddle?

Comment: you also need to define background-size/position: https://jsfiddle.net/3mje7oza/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to my comment you can use multiple background to keep the round boutton:

```css
input[type="range"] {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EDF1F0, #F6F8F7);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline:none;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: 
   url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-1-2/380/Arrow_Right2-512.png') center/contain no-repeat content-box,
   lightgray;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  padding:5px; /* Offset the background image from the edges */
}

input[type="range"]:before {
  content: "Modtag penge";
  color: #8a8a8a;
  position: absolute;
  left: 36%;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input #unlock type="range" class="slideToUnlock" value="0" max="100" (touchend)="checkUnlock($event)" (mouseout)="checkUnlock($event)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Inputs don't allow for :before and :after pseudo elements. Try setting `background` attributes like this:

```css
input[type="range"] {
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EDF1F0), to(#F6F8F7));
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-1-2/380/Arrow_Right2-512.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-color: lightgray;
  background-origin: content-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type="range"]:before {
  content: "TEST";
  color: #8a8a8a;
  position: absolute;
  left: 36%;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input #unlock type="range" class="slideToUnlock" value="0" max="100" (touchend)="checkUnlock($event)" (mouseout)="checkUnlock($event)">
```

Comment: This does work however is there a way to keep the round button?

Comment: You mean putting the arrow on round button?

Comment: Yes exactly is that possible?